# Need a Gridview to be added in view and also i would need to extended HTMLHelper class to manipulate(Paging, sorting) the Grid

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2

Can you let me know about adding Gridview control / similar control in MVC2 also i would like to have the sorting, paging options to that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this Stack Overflow document seems to cover the most popular and reliable options@

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations